# currentStyle.<propertyName> is returning null in cq5 publisher, which is working perfectly fine in author

Tags: aem, sightly

I am using sightly to access the design dialog properties for a component.
something like

```
<span data-sly-test="${currentStyle.delimiter}">${currentStyle.delimiter}</span>
```

but all I am getting is an empty string.

I tried to resolve the issue by trying out the following.

1. Activating the design node
2. Deleting the page and creating a new page.
3. Deleting components and dragging and dropping the  component again on the page.
4. I checked the JSON output of currentDesign and all the values am trying to access are available there.

Comment: Did you check if the author and publish are pointing to / fetching from the same design?

Comment: how can i ensure this?

Comment: Generally, the design for a site is set in the homepage page. You should find a `cq:designPath` property in the homepage `jcr:content` node. In case the design path is not mentioned, then it would be `/etc/designs/default`. You can also check using `${currentStyle.path}` to check the path of your currentStyle

Comment: i checked that cq:designPath is same in author and publish but when i am using ${currentStyle.path} to get the path in author and publish then there is a slight difference i.e. author:
`/etc/designs/corporate/global/<appname>/jcr:content/page/par-main/column-control/par-col-1/<componentname>`
publish:
`/etc/designs/corporate/global/<appname>/jcr:content/page/column-control/par-col-1/<componentname>`

Comment: More over design properties are getting stored at `/etc/designs/corporate/global/<appname>/jcr:content/page/par-main/column-contro‌​l/par-col-1/<componentname>` only for both the instances.

Comment: Is your /etc/designs/..... replicated? Is it present on your publish instance?

Comment: yes, it is present. please refer to (http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.5_ciot.html/forum__9rn2-i_checked_thatcqde.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

1. In preview/ publish mode fetch the design values via
   currentDesign.getJSON(), parse the value returned from that and then
   key into the values You want from the Json object.
2. You may solve this by removing one line of code from your template
   head.js. if you are inheriting any template from one of the "/libs"
   ( sightly)  page and there head.js will be having below line of code
   so you can just overlay head.js in your template and commented out
   below line of code.

`if (wcmmode.disabled) {
    request.setAttribute(Packages.com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext.
                  BYPASS_COMPONENT_HANDLING_ON_INCLUDE_ATTRIBUTE, true);
}`

Comment out this and everything was back to normal.